# Why doesn't the "if" condtion work properly alone in this python script?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a simple python script that creates a 7x7 list of dots '.', I want to change the diagonal to stars '*'. 
Here is my script

```
n=7
l=['.']*n
m=[l]*n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i==j:
            m[i][j]='*'
    print(*m[i])
```

Here is the output I get

```
* . . . . . .
* * . . . . .
* * * . . . .
* * * * . . .
* * * * * . .
* * * * * * .
* * * * * * *
```

I don't understand why I have such output, when I added an else statement it works fine.
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `m` consist of `n` references to `l` list.

So when you're modyfing `m[i][j] = '*'` you're constantly replacing consecutive `.` with `*` in the same list.

Here's sample which will help you understand this problem:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l1 = l
>>> l2 = l.copy()
>>> l1[0] = None
>>> l2[1] = None
>>> l
[None, 2, 3]
>>> l1
[None, 2, 3]
>>> l2
[1, None, 3]
```

You can fix your code by replacing `m = [l] * n` with `m = [l.copy() for _ in range(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not because of the `if` condition not working, but this `m = [l] * n`  creates an array of size `n`, with all being the same copy of the array `l`, like `[l, l, l, l, l, l, l]`

You can see what I am saying with this script:

```py
l=['.']*n
m=[l]*n
m[1][1] = '*'
```

`m` is now:

```py
[
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
  ['.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
]
```

What you can do is something like:

```py
m = [ ['.'] * n for i in range(n) ]
```

Like this, `m` does not have references of same array. Therefore you can safely mutate any elements without affecting other rows:

```py
n = 7
m = [ ['.'] * n for i in range(n) ]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i==j:
            m[i][j]='*'
    print(*m[i])
```

outputs:

```py
* . . . . . .
. * . . . . .
. . * . . . .
. . . * . . .
. . . . * . .
. . . . . * .
. . . . . . *
```

Comment: I had identified the issue but was not able to think of the way to fix it. is there any alternative for this like using l[::], I can use this only for making copy of l not able to use in this case